# C programming: Boolean

Tags: c, boolean

I have a quick question regarding Boolean and its false and true values. I know that 0=false and 1=true, but according to the code I have been given as an example, it says otherwise.

Why is it equal to 0, when we want to find all the users below 23 and with a BEL nationality?

```
void opgave_1 (loebsdata2017 *alle_loebsdata2017 ) {
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_RYTTERE; i++) {
        if(alle_loebsdata2017[i].rytteralder < 23 &&
           strcmp(alle_loebsdata2017[i].nationalitet, "BEL") == 0)
        {
            printf("%s %s %d %s \n", alle_loebsdata2017[i].rytternavn,
               alle_loebsdata2017[i].rytterhold,
               alle_loebsdata2017[i].rytteralder,
               alle_loebsdata2017[i].nationalitet);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Impossible to answer without knowing the input and the calling code etc. I see no apparent problem in the code posted. You would be best off running this code through your debugger and watch the values of the variables.

Comment: Where do you see a boolean equal to 0 in that code? If you mean the last part of the `if` condition, you should take a look at manual for `strcmp` function.

Comment: do you mean the return value of `strcmp()`? `strcmp()` does not return a bool, it returns an integer

Comment: It looks like the question  "Why is it equal to 0" is better asked as "Why compare `strcmp()` to 0?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When

```
strcmp(alle_loebsdata2017[i].nationalitet, "BEL") == 0
```

this can be considered as:

`alle_loebsdata2017[i].nationalitet` is equal to `"BEL"`

because the `strcmp()` function returns `0` when the strings being compared are equal.

from:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcmp.htm

Answer (score 1):

The `0` occurring in your code is not boolean.

Quoting from strcmp spec, e.g. http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp

> Return value
>   Negative value if lhs appears before rhs in lexicographical order.
>   Zero if lhs and rhs compare equal.
>   Positive value if lhs appears after rhs in lexicographical order.

So the comparison to `0` checks wether the string is equal to "BEL", exactly what you describe.